# Error propagation for benchmark composed of many tasks

Tags: nlp

Let's take the GLUE benchmark which is composed of many individual tasks. For each of these tasks, I am running experiments a few times (changing random seed) and calculate mean and std. How to calculate the score for the whole benchmark and its uncertainty?